# Unable to get the MCDC coverage for this line " while (v > 1 && !(v & INIT_STATUS_OK)) {"

Tags: c, unit-testing, mc-dc

I was trying to get the MCDC coverage for the code. but the test cases which Iam writing is not able to get the coverage of "!(v & INIT_STATUS_OK))" of the line

while (v > 1 && !(v & INIT_STATUS_OK))
{}

Can anyone help me to get the MCDC of that line.

```
`The test cases which Iam writing to get the coverage is below, 
`/* CPPTEST_TEST_CASE_BEGIN test_ddsrt_init_M1 */
/* CPPTEST_TEST_CASE_CONTEXT void ddsrt_init(void) */
void TestSuite_cdtors_c_6554c51a_test_ddsrt_init_M1()
{
    /* Pre-condition initialization */
    /* Initializing global variables */
    {
        init_status.v = 0u;
    }
    {
        /* Set v to 2 */
        uint32_t v = 2;

        /* Modify init_status with v having the INIT_STATUS_OK flag set */
        init_status.v |= INIT_STATUS_OK;

        /* Stub the atomic increment operation */
        ddsrt_atomic_inc32_nv_ExpectAndReturn(&init_status, v);

        /* Tested function call */
        ddsrt_init();

        /* Post-condition check */
        /*CPPTEST_POST_CONDITION_UINTEGER("uint32_t init_status.v", init_status.v);*/
        /*CPPTEST_POST_CONDITION_UINTEGER("uint32_t v", v);*/
        /*CPPTEST_POST_CONDITION_BOOL("v > 1", (v > 1));*/
        /*CPPTEST_POST_CONDITION_BOOL("!(v & INIT_STATUS_OK)", !(v & INIT_STATUS_OK));*/
    }
}
/* CPPTEST_TEST_CASE_END test_ddsrt_init_M1 */`
```

`